# iPhone app graphic elements

Tags: iphone, graphics

Where do you usually grab graphics for your iPhone apps?

Are any free official repos from Apple or one have to buy everything from thirdparty artists?

For example, does anyone know where I can find close button image like one one on this screenshot? Or it is private image?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doesn't really provide any images other than the system tab- and bar-button items. Most developers just end up making their own or getting them from third parties, paid or otherwise. A search for “iPhone UI template” might well turn up something like what you're after, probably for free or on reasonable licensing terms.

If you're looking specifically for a “close”/“delete” button, I [made one a while ago](http://noahw.me/syfiles/delete-button-icon.png), though it looks more like the system one than the one in the image you posted; you're free to use it if you like.

Comment: There are a couple of button types you can use direct from the SDK complete with graphics - (UIButtonTypeInfoLight, UIButtonTypeInfoDark, UIButtonTypeContactAdd), but not much really to speak of!

Answer (score 2):

[365psd.com](http://365psd.com) is one of my favorite places to find some brilliantly beautiful interface elements.  They give you the PSD, instead of just the PNG, so that you can scale it or modify it to fit your needs.  It's like open source for graphic design.

Answer (score 0):

[Find icons](http://findicons.com/) and [icon finder](http://www.iconfinder.com/) is great resource to find different UI icon and graphics for apps